# SOS! How do I deploy multiple Laravel apps on a windows IIS server in a LAN

Tags: php, laravel, iis, web-deployment, lan

I am setting up an IIS server in readiness to host multiple PHP web apps. These will be used within our local network so no need internet access. I have read a lot of stuff on how to go about it but am getting lost even more. someone please help.

Comment: This look pretty straigt forward https://devopspoints.com/microsoft-iis-10-0-hosting-multiple-websites.html

Comment: Yes, it's good documentation, I also checked, you can follow this.  if any confusion in above documentation, you can also check this one - https://serverfault.com/questions/536866/how-to-host-pages-on-iis-for-a-domain-on-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configure-a-php-website-on-iis) for detailed steps about deploy php application on IIS.

Here are some main important points:

- Install IIS in control pannel(windows) or server manager(windows server).
- Configure php. Youcan download it from php official website or Web PI(more recommand). The version over php8 may not work on IIS.
- Make the physical path of site points to root folder of application. It will auto generate web.config. Set the permission of root folder to avoid 500 error.
- If you have multiples version of php, you can isntall [php manager](https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2018/05/php-manager-150-for-iis-10) to configure them.